# make the dots navigation faster from the owl carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, owl-carousel

I want to make the navigation slider faster when the user uses the dots navigation. The slides move so slow when you use the dots to change the slides.

I read in the Owl Carousel documentation that the `dotsSpeed` parameter is a boolean, but it doesn't say anything about whether I can put a value for the timing.

There is the only place where the `dotsSpeed` is, I put the timing in value like 1000 and nothing happened.

How can I speed up the dot navigation action?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
    nav: false,
    navRewind: true,
    navText: ['prev', 'next'],
    navSpeed: false,
    navElement: 'div',
    navContainer: false,
    navContainerClass: 'owl-nav',
    navClass: ['owl-prev', 'owl-next'],
    slideBy: 1,
    dotClass: 'owl-dot',
    dotsClass: 'owl-dots',
    dots: true,
    dotsEach: false,
    dotData: false,
    dotsSpeed: true,
    dotsContainer: false,
    controlsClass: 'owl-controls'
  });
});
```

```css
#owl-demo .item {
  margin: 3px;
}

#owl-demo .item img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-page {
  display: inline-block;
}

.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-page span {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #869791;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: block;
  height: 12px;
  margin: 5px 7px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  width: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.2/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.2/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="owl-demo">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="Owl Image" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="Owl Image" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="Owl Image" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="Owl Image" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="Owl Image" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="Owl Image" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="Owl Image" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="Owl Image" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Per the [source code](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/owl.carousel.js), `dotsSpeed` does seem to control the speed of the slide change as triggered by pagination dots. Can you create a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code to help demonstrate the problem?

Comment: @showdev http://jsfiddle.net/njvbLdaf/20/ I just need to change the speed of the transition of the slides by the navigation dots. Thanks

Comment: So this is solved? Post an answer if it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had success using `dotsSpeed` with version 2.2.1.
[Version 1.3.2](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.2/owl.carousel.js) does not seem to have `dotsSpeed` functionality.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
    items: 5,
    dots: true,
    dotsSpeed: 50
  });
});
```

```css
#owl-demo .item {
  margin: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <div class="item"><img src="//placehold.it/150x150" alt="Owl Image"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="//placehold.it/150x150" alt="Owl Image"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="//placehold.it/150x150" alt="Owl Image"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="//placehold.it/150x150" alt="Owl Image"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="//placehold.it/150x150" alt="Owl Image"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="//placehold.it/150x150" alt="Owl Image"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="//placehold.it/150x150" alt="Owl Image"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="//placehold.it/150x150" alt="Owl Image"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="//placehold.it/150x150" alt="Owl Image"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="//placehold.it/150x150" alt="Owl Image"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="//placehold.it/150x150" alt="Owl Image"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="//placehold.it/150x150" alt="Owl Image"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="//placehold.it/150x150" alt="Owl Image"></div>
</div>
```